# Регулярное выражение для js regex

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Есть проблемы с написанием регулярного выражения. Задача: Создать регулярное выражение с набором правил

- только латиница
- общее количество символов - от 8 до 30
- Должно включать в себя либо хотя-бы одну цифру, либо хотя-бы один спецсимвол. (хотя бы либо одно, либо другое, или все сразу)

Пример: TestTest5 , TestTest! , TestTest!5

Выражение формата: ^((?=.*\d)(?=.*\W)(?=.*[A-Z]).{8,30})$ требует ввод и спецсимвола и цифры обязательно. По отдельности - не срабатывает.

Переписанное под "Или" выражение ^(({(?=.*\d)|(?=.*\W)})(?=.*[A-Z]).{8,30})$ не работает. Верятно - написано криво синтаксически. Буду очень признателен с решением текущей проблемы.

Answer (score 0):

Решение найдено:

```
^(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])((?=.*\d)|(?=.*[@$!%*#?&]))[A-Za-z\d@$!%*#?&]{8,}$
```